# Contar veces que se repite un elemento en una arreglo con php

Tags: php, array

¿Existe alguna función en `php` que me retorne la cantidad de veces que está repetido un elemento dentro de un `array`?. Si no es así, tendré que recorrer cada elemento y mediante un contador ver cuántas veces se repite.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo así, como la función `count()` que tiene `Python`. La salida de ese programa sería 2, ya que el uno esta presente dos veces en el `array`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con la funcion `array_count_values`

```
$valores = array_count_values($array);
```

La respuesta te entregada cuantas el numero y cuantas veces se repite

```
Array
(
       [1] => 2
       [2] => 2
       [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: Gracias, me fue util.

Comment: La respuesta está bien, así que va +1. Pero es importante comprobar que `$array` sea un array y que el valor buscado exista en el resultado mediante `array_key_exists`. Por ejemplo, lo tenés en mi respuesta ;)

Comment: @ESL gracias por el comentario!

Answer (score 5):

Veo dos opciones, que no tendrían inconvenientes al buscar valores con coma o comillas.

La primera opción sería la que mencionan [@sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16349/sioesi) y [@alvaro-montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro), **al ser nativa sea probablemente muy rápida**. En este caso, tenés que tener cuidado ya que si el valor no existe, no podés encontrarlo:

```
<?php
function contar_valores($a,$buscado)
 {
  if(!is_array($a)) return NULL;
  $v=array_count_values($a);
  return array_key_exists($buscado,$a)?$v[$buscado]:0;
 }
```

Pero eso sí, si te interesa comparar un solo valor, está creando en memoria un *array* con un elemento por cada valor único. Por ejemplo, `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1)`, que tiene 11 de largo, genera otro de 10 elementos de largo:

```
array(
       [1]=>2,
       [2]=>1,
       [3]=>1,
       [4]=>1,
       [5]=>1,
       [6]=>1,
       [7]=>1,
       [8]=>1,
       [9]=>1,
       [10]=>1,
)
```

Con esas cantidades no debería haber problema, pero si tratás arrays largos puede consumir mucha memoria, porque creás uno de tamaño similar.

En cambio, si intentás contar un solo valor, es más sencillo recorrer el array y comparar cada valor, usando `foreach`. Podés hacerlo en una sola línea (2 instrucciones) si estás seguro de que `$a` es un array: `$i=0;foreach($a as $v) if($buscado===$v) $i++;`

Si lo querés como función, podés hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
function contar_valores($a,$buscado)
 {
  if(!is_array($a)) return NULL;
  $i=0;
  foreach($a as $v)
   if($buscado===$v)
    $i++;
  return $i;
 }
```

Así, debería ser más eficiente en el manejo de memoria, ya que sólo crea una variable numérica.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Por lo general, las funciones nativas de PHP siempre ganan. Benchmark: http://ideone.com/ViIHJH

Comment: ¡Excelente aporte, @Mariano!

Answer (score 1):

No existe una función que te devuelva exactamente el número de veces que aparece un valor en concreto, pero podrías utilizar la función [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php) para contar cuántas veces aparecen todos los datos del array.

A partir de ahí podrías crear tu propia función:

```
function cuenta_veces_valor($array, $valor) {
    $contadores = array_count_values($array);
    return $contadores[$valor];
}
```

Aunque me imagino que, a no ser que necesites contar más de un elemento, puede ser un poco excesivo.

Comment: Gracias, me fue util.

Comment: De todas formas, debe recorrer todo el array para contar la cantidad. Sólo podría ser excesivo en memoria si hubiese muchos valores distintos. Por ejemplo `array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1)` daría como resultado un array con 10 elementos para un array original de 11.

Comment: Lo que sí no veo la necesidad de ponerlo en una variable.

Comment: La otra alternativa es hacer un `$i=0; foreach($array as $v) if($buscado==$v) $i++;`, que tiene un uso más eficiente de la memoria (lo que no significa que sea mejor, ya que `array_count_values` es una función nativa de PHP.

Comment: Hecho, de paso soluciono el problema de que de error si no existe el valor buscado (cuando debería devolver 0).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
$arr = array('amigo','Hola','amigo','amigo','samigo','amigos','que','tal','tal','tal','amigo');
$str = ", " . implode(", ",$arr) . ",";
$count = substr_count($str, ' amigo,');
echo $str."<br>";
echo $count;
```

Básicamente pasamos el arreglo a string y luego substr_count() nos hace el trabajo, verás que la salida es "3" pues la palabra "amigo" aparece tres veces en tu arreglo.

OJO que el elemento `'amigo,'` igual sumará `+1` a `$count`, pues tiene una coma al final, pero no quieres contabilizarlo pues es un elemento diferente al elemento 'amigo' , que no lleva coma.

Ten en cuenta que esto podría ser ineficiente en el manejo de memoria si procesas grandes cantidades de datos(estás copiando todos los datos en un string).

Comment: Gracias, me fue util tambien.

Comment: Deberías buscar `" amigo "` (con espacios), si no corres el riesgo de que cuente "amigos" como una ocurrencia de "amigo" (por ejemplo).

Comment: excelente acotación, la edito.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro podrías decirme si le ves algún error ahora?

Comment: Creo que para que funcione deberías añadir una coma al principio y final (`$str = "," . implode(",",$arr) . ",";`) y luego comprobar la cadena con coma al principio y final también (`$count = substr_count($str, ',amigo,');`). De lo contrario si la cadena buscada es la primera o la última del array, no se contaría

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahora lo he arreglado definitivamente.

Comment: Sí, ahora parece que ese problema ya está solucionado.

Comment: Me parece terrible esta respuesta, puede dar lugar a bugs (incluso de inseguridad). Si uno de los valores incluye coma se te fue todo al joraca. Además es terriblemente ineficiente en el manejo de memoria (estás copiando todos los datos en un string).

Comment: @ESL lo vi como una opción simple, tienes razón en cuanto a que podría ser ineficiente con grandes cantidades de datos, el único bug que podría presentar es si hay un elemento con una coma al final. Gracias por la observación, ya edité para aclararlo.